# circle background of different color for todays date

Tags: android, calendarview

I am using the prolific interactive android material calendarview in my app.

Is it possible to set a different colored circle background for todays date? Note this color is different than the selection date color background. I am able to set mcv_selectionColor for selected date. But I want to always show a different colored circle background for todays date irrespective of the fact its selected or not.I created a decorator for today's date only. But this decorator creates a square background.

```
public class TodaysDateDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {

private final Drawable highlightDrawable;
private final int color = Color.parseColor("#987d48");
private CalendarDay date;

public TodaysDateDecorator() {
    highlightDrawable = new ColorDrawable(color);
    date = CalendarDay.today();
}

@Override
public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
    return date != null && day.equals(date);
}

@Override
public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
    view.addSpan(highlightDrawable);
    view.addSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the docs, you should be able to create a custom ColorDrawable class and override get outline.

```
@Override
public void getOutline(@NonNull Outline outline) {
    outline.setOval(getBounds());
    outline.setAlpha(getAlpha() / 255.0f);
}
```